# Maven test dependencies of dependency

Tags: unit-testing, maven, scope, dependencies

I have a parent project which has dependencies with scope *test*

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.31.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now I "mvn install"ed the parent project, when I include this parent project as dependency in my child project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>parentproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

`selenium-firefox-driver` is not available. The *compile* scoped dependencies are available.

How can I make it available? I won't change the scope neither in the parent project nor in the child project. Because I need some classes of the parent in at runtime

Answer (score 5):

As outlined by Charlee Chitsuk in his answer, your scope (*compile* in the child project) will omit the *test* dependencies of the included project.

A clean solution would be to separate the concerns of the *parent* project into two separate projects:

- parent-test: This project includes your test dependencies (e.g. `selenium-firefox-driver`) with a *compile* scope. Additionally, this project contains all of your generic test resources, e.g. JUnit base classes, in `src/main/java`.
- parent-business: This project contains only the business functionality of the parent project. Include `parent-test` here with `test` scope.

In your child project, you can now include `parent-test` with scope *test* as well, giving you access to its resources with the right scope.

This setup will provide a clear project structure with clean scoping, avoiding issues like you have mentioned. Yes, it's a bit more complex due to the additional project, but it's a lot cleaner as well.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of including the parent project as dependency in your child pom, you should make the parent project as the `parent` of your child pom.

```
<parent>
   <groupId>group</groupId>
   <artifactId>parentproject</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

You cannot call it a `parent project` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) told that the `compile` is the default scope, used if none is specified. It affects transitive dependencies in different ways. By overview if the dependency is `compile` scope, the transitive `test` scope will be omitted. Please see further information at [Maven: The Complete Reference: Project Dependencies](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html).